# Django save_model file not yet uploaded

Tags: python, django

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
```

in this handler I can get the name of the uploaded file, but the file itself is not uploaded yet, so I can't make any operations on it, can be there a way to force django to upload that file in this `save_model` handler? in order to do some operations on it

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

    obj.save()
    super(FileAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    //here i am getting the file name its there, but the file itself is not uploaded
```

Comment: The file is most definitely uploaded by then. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i am trying to read it, it isn't there, but after this methods executes is there, i just wanna get that point when it is there, I just dont know which methods should be executed, and what makes you think that the file is there?

Comment: Please show your code. The `save_model` method is called after the form has been processed (in `changeform_view`), and it is the form which is responsible for processing the uploaded file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I posted the code, thats all i have the file isn't there when I'am trying to reach it at that point, even tought i call obj.save() - but it doesn't upload the file in the filesystem at this point

Comment: I mean show the code you are using to verify that the file is not uploaded.